# NavLink react-router-dom components :hover not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The hover does not work on react router components.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNGcY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and even shouldn't put pseudo-classes inline. Put css in class and then apply it by `className` like in example below:

**JSX:**

```
<NavLink to="/example" className="nav_link">Example</NavLink>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
  //other styles
  //...
  a.nav_link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red; 
  }
}
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vyyrpo5kxy)

Answer (score 2):

JSX inline style attributes does not allow `:hover`. You need to put that in your stylesheet instead.

Comment: Exactly, you should define a CSS class and its :hover class, and use that as `className` for `NavLink`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the CSS-in-JS method to set the class like so:

```
nav_link: {
  textDecoration: 'none',
  '&:hover': {
    textDecoration: 'none'
  }
}
```